# IBM AIX Vs Intel Performance

Tags: performance, aix, intel

Can anyone help me in comparing the performance of an `IBM AIX 570 Power 5 8 Cores` computer with the latest `Intel 6 Cores`.

Thanks

Comment: doing what? this question is unanswerable as it stands, and you'd probably go to a xeon 75xx series from an AIX machine, they have 8 cores per socket plus hyperthreading and you have have 4/8 or more per server too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this sounds like it should be an easy question to answer, it really is a huge "it depends".

You can compare the performance of a Power 7880 server with 4 [Power7 CPU](http://www.spec.org/cpu2006/results/res2010q2/cpu2006-20100426-10753.html) running at 4.14 Ghz for a total of 16 cores running the SPEC INT 2006 benchmark to a server with 4 [Xeon E7-4807](http://www.spec.org/cpu2006/results/res2011q2/cpu2006-20110328-15349.html) processors, total of 24 cores, running the same benchmark, and find that the SPECInt result for the Power7 box is 44 compared to 23 for the Intel processors, but that really doesn't tell you much.

You need to look at application specific details, and the best place to start is IBM themselves - if you're comparing Intel to Power, ask for comparisons between Systems X and P for the same budget, and see what you can get from them.

Answer (score 1):

IBM has many comparison charts for probably any workload of which you can think.  Check with your IBM reseller/partner.